# Limiting log size for a particular topic in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to limit log size for a kafka topic.

I followed the **kafka documentation(Kafka 0.10.0 Documentation)** and set these two property **cleanup.policy=delete,retention.bytes=1.**

--> result of topic describe command

> ./kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic
>   kafkatest1 Topic:kafkatest1        PartitionCount:3
>   ReplicationFactor:1
>   Configs:cleanup.policy=delete,retention.bytes=1

I was expecting that whatever message i am writing to topic 'kafkatest1' will get deleted automatically since i have set retention.bytes to 1.
but messages are keep getting appended.

Is there any additional configuration is required to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `log.segment.bytes` (the default is 1073741824 bytes). As far as I know the retention will be taken into account when a log segment is rolled.

Could you explain what you are trying to a achieve? Why sending a message to delete it?

Comment: I tried changing 'segment.bytes' to 15 bytes. But still no success.

I trying out to limit size on per topic basis.so that same kafka cluster can be shared among multiple user. I kept 'retention.bytes=1' so that I can verify this functionality using console consumer itself.

Comment: Does that had any effects?